# Does Chromecast Ultra Limit HTML Resolution?

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to get Chromecast Ultra to display a 3840x2160 web page.  It has no problem when the content is a simple IMG but when I try an iframe or some more complicated HTML it crops it down to what looks like the top left but less than a quarter of the whole screen.

I tried Casting (mirroring) from a Chrome tab of the same website that gives me what looks like 1920x1080.  A simple image shows full res.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js">
  </script>
<style>
  body {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #f0f000;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    width: 100%;  //this is important
    height: 100%;  //this is important
}

  iframe {
    width: 3840px;
    height: 2160px;
    min-width: 3840px;
    min-height: 2160px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!--<img src="EdAGGFS.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.</img>-->

<iframe id="test" src="https://sorrycantshowyou.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

  <script>
    const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
    const options = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();
    //options.maxInactivity = 3600; //Development only
    options.disableIdleTimeout = true;
    context.start(options);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm plum out of ideas to test any further.  I can't find any reference that gives Chromecast Ultra specs for HTML content.  I am just assuming it should be capable of 3840x2160 like video or images.  Am I wrong?  Maybe Chromecast's processor is not up to rendering HTML that big so it crops it instead?

Comment: Just noticed that the top line (<html....) in the chrome debugger shows the resolution as 1280x720.  Nowhere am I setting that.  Looks like the Chromecast device is forcing it.

Answer (score 0):

That is an [expected behavior](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) for Chromecast.

> Note: Images have a display size limitation of 720p (1280x720). Images
>   should be optimized to 1280x720 or less to avoid scaling down on the
>   receiver device.

Also, it was mentioned in one of the [Chromecast product review online](https://www.trustedreviews.com/news/chromecast-4k-ultra-vs-chromecast-2-whats-the-difference-2944328).

> The Chromecast 2 displays content in Full HD 1080p resolution – that’s
>   1,920 x 1,080 pixels. Regardless of whether you have a Full HD or 4K
>   TV, you’ll still only be able to watch 1080p footage. And if you have
>   a 720p HD TV, the content will be downscaled to 1,280 x 720 pixels.

Comment: I had read that but they were referring to Chromecast 1 and 2.  I had expected Ultra (being FOR 4K) might have stepped up still image capability.  Certainly the built-in  slideshow appears to be a lot bigger resolution.